# When to use 聴く vs 聞く vs 訊く?

Tags: kanji, verbs, homophonic-kanji

When should one use 聴く instead of 聞く? Is there a precise rule for which one to use in which situation?

I have a feeling that 聞 is used more when the source of the sound is a person or other living being, whereas 聴 is reserved for when the source of the sound is a inanimate object. Am I correct?

What about 訊く?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When I see 聴 my mind basically jumps first to 音楽を聴く. As mentioned this has the meaning of *listening* to something with some sort of interest in it. You might want to connect it to the word 傾聴, which means "to listen intently," or roughly that. Of course you can use 聞く in that sentence but that kanji has a broader meaning of hearing in general. The difference is basically the same as that between 見る and 観る, as in 犬を見た vs. 映画を観た.

Asking questions has its own dedicated kanji as well: 訊く. You could probably translate this as "inquire," as using that kanji gives it a slightly more refined feel, and I think that this holds true for the others as well. The choice to use these kanji is deliberate and creates extra nuance as to the nature of what you are hearing (vs. listening), seeing (vs. watching), asking (vs. inquiring), etc.

Just a note from the [dictionary](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%81%B4%E3%81%8F) on the usage of 聴く:

> (2)心を落ち着け注意して耳に入れる。傾聴(けいちよう)する。《聴》 
>   「音楽を―・く」

And 訊く:

> (4)（「訊く」とも書く）たずねて、答えを求める。問う。 
>   「名前を―・く」「自分の胸に―・く」

Answer (score 8):

I think of the difference between 聴く and 聞く as the difference between "to listen" and "to hear". That is,

> 彼の話を聴いてる.
> I'm listening to his story.

but

> 音が聞こえてる.
> I can hear sounds.
>
> 大きい音を聞くと気持ち悪くなる。
> If I hear loud noise, I start feeling sick.

(which are examples contrary to your animate/inanimate hypothesis).

Intentional listening should be 聴く, the hearing of sounds should be 聞く.

Comment: Can 聴 also be used for 'to ask' with a similar nuance?

Comment: actually to ask you might even use 訊く

Comment: Since this answer was posted, the asker added 訊く to their question.

Comment: @snailplane Thanks. I was away for an hour, and now it seems I missed all the action. I'll need to add something, or else this answer will just be obsolete. =)

Comment: @downvoter Please leave a comment.

Comment: maybe 聞く and 聞こえる are not the same verb ?

Comment: @oldergod It's easy to find examples with 聞く rather than 聞こえる, where it still means "hearing" and not "listening".

Comment: And I don't see the OP asking about 聞こえる, do you ?

Comment: @oldergod I consider 聞こえる the potential form of 聞く, at least when it means "to hear". (The OP also didn't ask about 聴いてる.)

Comment: Great Answer. I guess you don't consider 聞ける being the potential form of 聞く and you must be right. I bet you `consider` that 見える is the potential form of 見る and that is great.

Comment: @oldergod I consider 聞ける the potential form of 聞く when it means "to ask".